# VBA: newline and carriage return character for an Excel (.xlxs) file with Korean/French

Tags: vba, character-encoding

I'm having quite a bit of trouble replacing the newline and carriage return characters in an Excel file (2010 US version and .xlxs extension).

Previously, I have written a macro that does this successfully on a regular Excel file with English with the following code.

```
newStr = Replace(originalStr, newline/carriage return/both, replacementStr)
```

`Newline/carriage return/both` would be vbNewLine (Chr(10)), vbCr (Chr(13)), or vbCrLf, respectively.

I now have an Excel file with Koreans and French in it, and the newline and CR characters seem to be something else. How do I go about finding what they actually are, in terms of `Chr()`) or some VBA constant, and replace these characters? I need to remove all of the newlines and replace with `<br />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you select a relevant cell and check the characters contained, like so:

```
s = Sheets("Sheet3").[e2]

For i = 1 To Len(s)
    If Asc(Mid(s, i, 1)) < 32 Then
        Debug.Print Asc(Mid(s, i, 1)); " -- "; i
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hm wow.. This is very strange. Using `Replace()` with `Chr(10)` now works. I swear it did not work the yesterday, and I couldn't catch the newlines to in PHP either! I wonder if changing the language from US English to Korean, then back to US made some difference? I did notice that some of my Excel forms created had their column width all changed.

Comment: According to recent research, in 73.231% of cases, reporting a problem dissipates it :)